# How do we find the most similar objects from the list of objects?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search, hash, big-o

Suppose I have a list A containing 1000 objects of same class with different properties.

How can I extract the list of most similar objects corresponding to a certain set of property values?

By similar I mean having least difference in property values?

For Example:

I have a class like:

```
class Cat{
   string breed;
   string color;
   int age;
   int weight;  // in kgs
}
```

There are many objects in the list ( more than 1000 ) like:

```
Cat('Persian', 'white', 2, 5)
Cat('Bengal', 'spotted brown', 1.5, 3)
Cat('Siamese', 'dark gray/white', 2, 4)
Cat('Sphynx', 'light gray', 3, 8)
Cat('Ragdoll', 'white', 1, 2)
```

Now I want to sort the above list on the basis of maximum similarity to another object say:

```
Cat('Chartreux', 'dark gray', 2.5, 6)
```

How can I compare multiple values at once with lowest possible running time?
Consider all the properties as of equal importance.

Comment: Sort the array using quicksort (O(n log n)) using the properties you want to compare. Then iterate through the array checking the current property with the next property. Store the similar items in another array. Total complexity is O(n log n + n).

Comment: @MichaelBianconi Suppose you have a list of integers and you want a list of the 3 integers that are closest to each other. This is pretty much the same thing that OP is asking. If you have `1 3 4 6 7 9 10 12 13` (already sorted), which ones do you take? `1 3 4`, `3 4 6`, `7 9 10`, `9 10 12` or `10 12 13` ?

Comment: Probably a sliding window algorithm

Comment: @MichaelBianconi What I mean is that the distance between the numbers is the same, but the numbers are different. What are the criteria to say that one list is better than the other? This is not specified. Also, this gets worse because it's not one parameter, it's multiple, so is it better to have a bunch of parameters where all have distance 2, or where some have distance 3 and some have distance 1? This is also not specified. That's why this is a badly formulated question in my opinion

Comment: When there are multiple pairs with the same similarity, it's convention to choose either the first or last one. The difference between a 2/2 set and a 3/1 also doesn't seem to matter. This isn't a good question, but it's not unanswerable. It's just not worth answering (he hasn't put any work in).

Comment: You can use custom comparator and wrote the logic to compare objects based on set of properties, and count what all are matched. and then sort based on this count.

Comment: I would suggest you to get an elegant answer you should give some examples for better understanding of question.

Comment: @MichaelBianconi: I would suggest that it's pretty well unanswerable as is.  Randomly pick a single element from the list.: See, here's my list, and there are absolutely no differences between any two distinct members of the list (vacuously, but so what?).  No, that's not what you want?  OK, keep one member of every equivalence class modulo our difference metric.  That's my list.  If we're looking for a fixed-length output we can probably make some reasonable calls, but without that, I think it's way underspecified.

Comment: @SalimShrestha: You need to add more details about what you're looking for.  A single element is most similar to itself.  So can I choose just that one element?  If not, why not?  How many elements need to be in the output list?  How do you choose between multiple distinct sets of the same size?  An example would go a long way here.

Answer (score 0):

`1` Create a method that compare 2 objects of the class.

`2` Sort the array based on this comparison method.

The most similar elements will stay together in the sorted array.